# boost-test 'filename'.test.report.xml not found

Tags: c++, xml, unit-testing, boost-test

I use `Visual Studio` adapter for `Boost.Test`. I built `boost.test[v1.59]` project using `cmake`.
I didn't have any compile problems but when I tried to run tests I got the output like below:

```
Executing:   -> [BoostUnitTestSample]

filestream was found to be null when handling path: D:\Work\Project\dev\DesktopMSVC13_Project\src\ProjectTest\Debug\ProjectTest.exe.test.report.xml

Exception caught while running test batch D:\Work\Project\dev\DesktopMSVC13_Project\src\ProjectTest\Debug\ProjectTest.exe [BoostUnitTestSample] 
(File 'D:\Work\Project\dev\DesktopMSVC13_Project\src\ProjectTest\Debug\ProjectTest.exe.test.report.xml' not found.)

========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:03,6081912) ==========
```

Everything goes fine if I add a `boost.test` project manually

Comment: What version of Boost.Test?

Comment: Please add that crucial detail _into the question_.

Comment: You will need to mention that you are using the Visual Studio adapter for Boost.Test, otherwise people get confused since these messages are generated by the extension not by Boost.Test.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with the [Boost.Test extension for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5f4ae1bd-b769-410e-8238-fb30beda987f) (see comment) tells me that you forgot to set references to dependencies required to run the tests (typically DLLs). I think the message is rather created by the standard test execution engine than by Boost.Test extension. It is just a clumsy way of saying "oh, the test did not run, so I could find the results..."

Comment: How to find why tests does not run? I checked `BoostTestAdapter.dll.log`.
`depends.exe {SolutionDir}\Debug\UnitTest.exe` also does not show anything.

Comment: I currently have a debugging problem with Visual Studio 2015, Boost 1.62 and Boost Unit Test extension v. 1.0.7.57. The tests are discovered, I can run the tests but I can't debug them. I can debug the unit test application the normal way ("Start debugging") but I can't  "Debug test". I am out of wisdom for now. I worked but I missed the moment it stopped working so currently no chance to fix it... :-(